Power Pivot Error - contains the blank value and that is not allowed for columns on the one side of a many-to-one relationship
I’m learning the Power Pivot and have encountered an issue while creating relationships between tables. I used already available data to practice and am now facing an error when attempting to establish these relationships.
Three Tables details

The error when I try to create a relationship

If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, I would greatly appreciate your insights!
Column Employee ID in table variance contains the blank value and that is not allowed for columns on the one side of a many-to-one relationship or for columns that are used as the primary key of the table

I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. You have blank values in the [Emy ID] column.
